# How to run html file using node js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js

I have a simple html page with angular js as follows:

```
    //Application name
    var app = angular.module("myTmoApppdl", []);

    app.controller("myCtrl", function ($scope) {
        //Sample login function
        $scope.signin = function () {
            var formData =
                    {
                        email: $scope.email,
                        password: $scope.password
                    };
        console.log("Form data is:" + JSON.stringify(formData));
    };
});
```

HTML file:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link href="bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
    </head>

    <body ng-app="myTmoApppdl" ng-controller="myCtrl">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="form-group">
                <form class="form" role="form" method="post" ng-submit="signin()">
                    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                        <label class="">Email address</label>
                        <input type="email" class="form-control" ng-model="email" id="exampleInputEmail2" placeholder="Email address" required>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                        <label class="">Password</label>
                        <input type="password" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword2" ng-model="password" placeholder="Password" required>
                    </div>
                </form>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Sign in</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>

    <script src="angular.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <!--User defined JS files-->
    <script src="app.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="jsonParsingService.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</html>
```

I am new to node js. I have installed node js server in my system but I am not sure how to run a simple html file using node js?

Comment: "Actually this will run even copy/pasted somewhere in your desktop."

Comment: You can't "run html file" with node.js. Node.js is a JavaScript environment for developing server-side Web applications. Html files are usually run by web-browsers.

Comment: Node.js does not "run" HTML files.  You probably just want a server that serves static files.

Answer (score 53):

You can use built-in nodejs web server.

Add file `server.js` for example and put following code:

```
var http = require('http');
var fs = require('fs');

const PORT=8080; 

fs.readFile('./index.html', function (err, html) {

    if (err) throw err;    

    http.createServer(function(request, response) {  
        response.writeHeader(200, {"Content-Type": "text/html"});  
        response.write(html);  
        response.end();  
    }).listen(PORT);
});
```

And after start server from console with command `node server.js`. Your index.html page will be available on URL `http://localhost:8080`

Comment: I should put this in file called `app.js`?

Comment: Do I have to add it to script tag in html?

Comment: @Satyadev It's doesn't matter how you call this file. This file is responsible for server side...

Comment: I am getting errors like this: `2 'require' was used before it was defined. var http = require('http');
5 Expected an identifier and instead saw 'const'. const PORT=8080;
5 Stopping. (26% scanned). const PORT=8080;`

Comment: It just prints `It Works!! Path Hit: /index.htm`

Comment: @Satyadev Sorry, it's my mistake... Use updated code!

Comment: Its ok I fixed the issue using the SO post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6084360/using-node-js-as-a-simple-web-server

Answer (score 34):

Just install **http-server** globally

`npm install -g http-server`

where ever you need to run a html file run the command http-server
For ex: your html file is in /home/project/index.html
 you can do `/home/project/$ http-server`

That will give you a link to accessyour webpages:
`http-server
Starting up http-server, serving ./
Available on:
  http://127.0.0.1:8080
  http://192.168.0.106:8080`

Comment: This is probably the most straightforward, no?

Comment: I don't think this is a great solution.  You should not install npm packages globally when it can be avoided.  The whole entire Node infrastructure has moved decidedly away from throwing a -g into everything.

Comment: I tried installing installing `http-server` without `-g` and node through an error when I tried to start the server. It seems that `-g` is still required when instaling this particular package.

Comment: Installing globally requires sudo so I installed without the `-g` in my project directory. Then, I ran `index.html`, which is in the project directory, as `node_modules/http-server/bin/http-server`.

Comment: Actually, I ran into a question--how to daemonize it? In the above method, it would run on a shell. So unless I use `screen` like app or able to keep my shell open forever, the server would get cut-off at some point.

Answer (score 18):

I too faced such scenario where I had to run a web app in nodejs with index.html being the entry point. Here is what I did:

- run `node init` in root of app (this will create a package.json file)
- install express in root of app : `npm install --save express` (save will update package.json with express dependency)
- create a public folder in root of your app and put your entry point file (index.html) and all its dependent files (this is just for simplification, in large application this might not be a good approach).
- Create a **server.js** file in root of app where in we will use express module of node which will serve the public folder from its current directory.
- server.js

  ```
  var express = require('express');
  var app = express();
  app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public')); //__dir and not _dir
  var port = 8000; // you can use any port
  app.listen(port);
  console.log('server on' + port);
  ```
- do `node server` : it should output "server on 8000"
- start http://localhost:8000/ : your index.html will be called

[File Structure would be something similar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Msj9P.jpg)

Comment: I found a better solution than mine : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6084360/using-node-js-as-a-simple-web-server?noredirect=1&lq=1 check out Tony's answer and upvote there.

Comment: I actually liked your answer more. It's quick and easy and uses native Node functionality without installing excessive packages.

Answer (score 11):

Move your HTML file in a folder "www". Create a file "server.js" with code :

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/www'));

app.listen('3000');
console.log('working on 3000');
```

After creation of file, run the command "node server.js"

Comment: This is the simplest configuration I see and worked like charm :)

Comment: cannot find module 'express'

Comment: @MindRoasterMir That's because [express is a package/framework](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32303730/1028230). You'd have to add it to your package.json first -- `npm install express` etc etc. More [at that other question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32303730/1028230). It is _much_ easier to use than `http`, however, especially if you want to serve, say, the CSS and other associated includes for your html file.

Comment: npm install --save express    is a prerequisite

Answer (score 7):

The simplest command by far:

`npx http-server`

This requires an existing index.html at the dir at where this command is being executed.

This was already mentioned by Vijaya Simha, but I thought using npx is way cleaner and shorter. I am running a webserver with this approach since months.

Docs: https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-server

Comment: it runs but not on my desired port, can you please how to assign on custom port? thank you

Comment: @AljohnYamaro `npx http-server -p 8080`

Answer (score 5):

http access and get the html files served on 8080:

```
>npm install -g http-server

>http-server
```

if you have public (./public/index.html) folder it will be the root of your server if not will be the one that you run the server. you could send the folder as paramenter ex:

```
http-server [path] [options]
```

expected Result:

*> Starting up http-server, serving ./public Available on:

> http://LOCALIP:8080
>
> http://127.0.0.1:8080
>
> Hit CTRL-C to stop the server
>
> http-server stopped.*

Now, you can run:
http://localhost:8080

will open the index.html on the ./public folder

references: https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-server

Answer (score 2):

This is a simple html file "demo.htm" stored in the same folder as the node.js file.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <h1>Heading</h1>
    <p>Paragraph.</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Below is the node.js file to call this html file.

```
var http = require('http');
var fs = require('fs');

var server = http.createServer(function(req, resp){
  // Print the name of the file for which request is made.
  console.log("Request for demo file received.");
  fs.readFile("Documents/nodejs/demo.html",function(error, data){
    if (error) {
      resp.writeHead(404);
      resp.write('Contents you are looking for-not found');
      resp.end();
    }  else {
      resp.writeHead(200, {
        'Content-Type': 'text/html'
      });
      resp.write(data.toString());
      resp.end();
    }
  });
});

server.listen(8081, '127.0.0.1');

console.log('Server running at http://127.0.0.1:8081/');
```

Intiate the above nodejs file in command prompt and the message
"Server running at http://127.0.0.1:8081/" is displayed.Now in your browser
type "http://127.0.0.1:8081/demo.html".

Comment: Your code is pretty unreadable with that spacing and indentation.  Please correct these to make it easier for future readers.

Answer (score 1):

Either you use a framework or you write your own server with nodejs.

A simple fileserver may look like this:

```
import * as http from 'http';
import * as url from 'url';
import * as fs from 'fs';
import * as path from 'path';

var mimeTypes = {
     "html": "text/html",
     "jpeg": "image/jpeg",
     "jpg": "image/jpeg",
     "png": "image/png",
     "js": "text/javascript",
     "css": "text/css"};

http.createServer((request, response)=>{
    var pathname = url.parse(request.url).pathname;
    var filename : string;
    if(pathname === "/"){
        filename = "index.html";
    }
    else
        filename = path.join(process.cwd(), pathname);

    try{
        fs.accessSync(filename, fs.F_OK);
        var fileStream = fs.createReadStream(filename);
        var mimeType = mimeTypes[path.extname(filename).split(".")[1]];
        response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type':mimeType});
        fileStream.pipe(response);
    }
    catch(e) {
            console.log('File not exists: ' + filename);
            response.writeHead(404, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
            response.write('404 Not Found\n');
            response.end();
            return;
    }
    return;
    }
}).listen(5000);
```

Comment: @SLaks Nice I did not know this package. PS. the posted code was only my debug version. The release version consists only of one `server.js` file.

Comment: @Matthias I followed the other answer posted by @JILeXanDR but it prints only `It Works!! Path Hit: /index.htm` after running. Could you please tell what I am doing wrong?

Comment: @Satyadev Yes, this is because of the line `response.end('It Works!! Path Hit: ' + request.url);` Maybe you should read a short tutorial about nodejs

Comment: You can replace the `import` statements by the `require` statements. Ans save this code. In `server.js` file too.

Answer (score 1):

In order to deploy a html pages via Node JS project, For example to deploy an Angular build file where the all the requests needed to be redirected to index.html in that case we can use the wild card route of node js to serve the Angular project but we need to make sure that there are no naming conflicts of Angular route and Node js API route.

**app.js**

```js
//Angular App Hosting Production Build
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/dist/ShoppingCart'));

// For all GET requests, send back index.html (PathLocationStrategy) (Refresh Error)
app.get('*', (req,res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '/dist/ShoppingCart/index.html'));
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
app.get('/home', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/home.html');
});
```

Comment: This answer is in the "low quality answers queue" and **may** be voted for deletion. I suggest you try to expand the content detail to avoid that happening.

Comment: Although this code might answer the question, I recommend that you also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to run the html file in your browser then you can do following steps:

step 1 --> You need to create server and listen on some port

step 1 eg --->

```
app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Server running at http://localhost:${PORT}/`);
});
```

step 2 --> You can make the route like `/` or `/profile` for your html webpage

step 2.1 --> Now in this route you can use `sendFile` function in node js

step 2.1 eg --->

```
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'index.html'));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const http = require('http');
const fs = require('fs');
var mimeTypes = {
    "html": "text/html",
    "jpeg": "image/jpeg",
    "jpg": "image/jpeg",
    "png": "image/png",
    "js": "text/javascript",
    "css": "text/css"
};

var server = http.createServer((req, res) => {
    if (req.url === '/') {
        res.writeHeader(200, { "Content-Type": "text/html" });
        fs.createReadStream('./public/index.html').pipe(res)
    }
    var filesDepences = req.url.match(/\.js|.css/);
    if (filesDepences) {
         var extetion = mimeTypes[filesDepences[0].toString().split('.')[1]];
        res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': extetion });
        fs.createReadStream(__dirname + "/public" + req.url).pipe(res)
    }
})

server.listen(8080);
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.

Comment: thanks I thought about what he needed, that's why I didn't make the code longer